# How to use pagination in Apache TinkerPop Gremlin?

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop, gremlin-server, gremlinpython

How to use `pagination` in `apache tinker pop gremlin`? Trying to get both `count` and the `vertex properties`

```
g.V().hasLabel('person').fold().as('persons','count').
       select('persons','count').
         by(range(local, 2, 4)).
         by(count(local))
```

**output:-**

```
{'persons': [v[2e6279e5-ad7c-48e3-9527-4972e55ecd24],
v[bb01581c-de6f-4c57-92f5-6fe090011279]], 'count': 36}
```

How to get the `properties of vertex` instead of just `T.id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding another answer just to point out a possible performance optimization. If there are a lot of people in the graph, materializing all the properties and then selecting just a few is potentially going to give the query engine a lot wasted work to do. It's often better to materialize results as late in the query as possible. Here's a minor rewrite to the other answer that does just that.

```java
g.V().hasLabel('persons').fold().as('persons','count').
       select('persons','count').
         by(range(local, 2, 4).unfold().elementMap().fold()).
         by(count(local))
```

Of course, I assume you have a scenario that is more complex as the example shown does not need the `fold` at all. You could just use a `union` step or something else that aggregates results.

```java
g.V().hasLabel('person').
      union(range(2,4).elementMap(),count()).
      fold()
```

Comment: `union example` count is not correct. it returns the count of `range`

Comment: I will update the answer to fix the count

Answer (score 0):

add `elementMap()` before `fold()`

```
g.V().hasLabel('persons').elementMap().fold().as('persons','count').
           select('persons','count').
             by(range(local, 2, 4)).
             by(count(local))
```